# Syntax error using CATX in SAS PROC SQL

Tags: sas

I am generating a syntax error in SAS 9.4 when trying to use CATX("|", of a1-a5) in PROC SQL.

Why do the first two outputs work, but the third fails?

```
data test;
    input a1 $ a2 $ a3 $ a4 $ a5 $;
    cards;
    a b c d e
    f g h i j
    k l m n o
    p q r s t
    u v w x y
    ;
run;

proc sql;
    select CATX('|',a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) as catx from test;
quit;

data test2;
    set test;
    catx=CATX('|',OF a1-a5);
run;
proc print data=test2; run;

proc sql;
    select CATX('|',OF a1-a5) as catx from test;
quit;
```

The first proc sql and the data step produce the expected "a|b|c|d|e", etc. But the third proc sql produces a syntax error pointed at the "a1":

```
32   proc sql;
33       select CATX('|',OF a1-a5) as catx from test;
                            --
                            22
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, (, *, **, +, ',', -, '.', /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, BETWEEN,
              CONTAINS, EQ, EQT, GE, GET, GT, GTT, LE, LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, OR, ^=, |, ||, ~=.
```

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you're stretching proc sql's flexibility / full integration with other parts of the sas language. The explicit way might unfortunately be your best shot here. Unless you have dozens of columns, in which case a macro variable could be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have hit one of those walls in Proc SQL where some base SAS functions are not fully supported. As someone mentioned earlier you're better off creating a macro variable containing the columns you need for your concatenation.

here is a quick example:

```
proc sql noprint;
select name into :cols separated by ','
from dictionary.columns
where libname = "WORK" and
memname = "TEST";
quit;
%put &cols;
proc sql;
    select CATX('|',&cols) as catx from test;
quit;
```

Obviously your `where` clause will be more complex as your original data set may contain columns not required in the `CATX` expression.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax "OF a1-a5" is specified for data-step code only.
"proc sql" sas procedure is a simpliest sql code and it cant't be mixed with data-step code.